# Checking if list exists client-side

Tags: list, splistitem, silverlight

I'm developing a Silverlight web part and can't use server-side objects like SPList. I normally get items from a list called "Locations" which has two fields - "Title" and "WOEID". The problem is I'd like my webpart to create that list in case it doesn't exist before getting data from it. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the classes of the [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client) namespace.
[Here is an example how to retrieve the lists of a site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538683).
[And here is an example how to add a new list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list).